# What allows us to take the adjoint of both sides of an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose that I have that $ST = TS =I$ Where $T,S \in L(V)$ What allows me to take the adjoint of all three sides to get:

$T^*S^*=S^*T^*=I^*=I$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. $A=B\Longrightarrow A^*=B^*$ isn't evident to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go back to the definition of the adjoint for this but.. if you want a quick(er) answer: $T^*S^* = (ST)^*$. We know that $I^* = I$ so in turn that says that $T^*S^* = I^* = I$ and likewise for the other equality.